# Facebook Programmatically Authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have a desktop application in Node.JS and many users. I want to send my user's posts to my Facebook page.
according to Facebook developers guide and the other related articles, I can not find a way to send a post with passing username,password,other information without showing login page to user.
Can I do this? because I want to send posts to my own page programmatically, (users don't have my password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use username/password for login to your App - it would be a major security problem anyway. You MUST go through the login process in order to authorize users, and you need to authorize them with the `publish_actions` permission.

This may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

Comment: does Google plus represent this feature?